# Why is Spring Boot Azure Function is replaying events?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an Spring Boot Azure Function configured using `@Eventhubtrigger`

```
public class MyHandler extends FunctionInvoker<Object, Object> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyHandler.class);

    @FunctionName("myFunction")
    public void execute(
        @EventHubTrigger(
            name="myEventHubTrigger",
            eventHubName="my-event-hub-sample"
            cardinality=Cardinality.ONE,
            consumerGroup="cg-my-event-hub-sample",
            connection = "EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STRING"
        ) String event, ExecutionContext context) {

        try {
            context.getLogger().log(new Record(LEVEL.INFO, "Event read"+event));
            LOGGER.info("Application : Event Read "+event);


            //this writes event to Blob Location
            handleRequest(event, context);

            LOGGER.info("Application : Event processed successfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Application : Event processed with error",e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the `handleRequest(event, context)`, writes to Azure Blob storage with `yyyy-mm-dd-timestamp` format.

Also I dont see any exceptions and can see in log message like : `Application : Event processed successfully` . Inspite of this, again the event is consumed and again the whole processing is done and again all messages are printed in log

Due to this behavior, I can see multiple files with different timestamps created at blob location for one single event dropped in eventhub. I just dropped one event in eventhub and 30 files were created at blob location. Sometimes its 15, sometimes its 30. Ideally only one file should be created at blob location.

What is missing here ?